# Installing a driver programmatically on Windows, driver doesn't become active

Tags: windows, installation, usb, device-driver

I have a program that installs a USB driver for a specific device and then updates the device firmware. I use SetupCopyOEMInf() for installing the driver, however, this function doesn't seem to be making the driver active unless I restart the system.

I.e. the installation goes OK, SetupCopyOEMInf() returns OK but the device still remains "Unknown" in the Device Manager unless I restart Windows. However, when I install the driver manually, the system recognizes everything fine and the device quickly gets bound to the driver.

Is there anything else apart from SetupCopyOEMInf() I should do so that the driver gets bound to the device?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I believe this is the expected behaviour: the function installs the driver but does not scan for devices that it is applicable to, and is generally used for installing drivers for devices that are not yet present.  Perhaps try [DiInstallDriver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff544717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead?  "The DiInstallDriver function preinstalls a driver in the driver store and then installs the driver on devices present in the system that the driver supports."

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks for pointing me in the right direction. DiInstallDriver seems to be an equivalent of SetupCopyOEMInf + UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices and is limited to 32-bit systems, but works Ok.

Comment: According to the documentation, at least, none of these functions are limited to 32-bit systems; however, on a 64-bit system, some of them can only be called by a 64-bit application.

Comment: @HarryJohnston they are limited unfortunately (except for SetupCopyOEMInf) see notes on ERROR_IN_WOW64 for DiInstallDriver

Comment: ERROR_IN_WOW64 means that you're trying to call the function from a 32-bit application on a 64-bit system.  If you use a 64-bit application the problem will go away.

Comment: @HarryJohnston sorry yes, I misread the docs. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try installing your driver using devcon, the source is available in the WDK, using `devcon dp_add mydriver.inf`. If this works you can step through the source in devcon to find out how to properly install your driver dynamically, devcon also uses SetupCopyOEMInf, so if it works you can compare this to your code to find out what the difference is, here is a snippet in case it helps you now:

```
TCHAR SourceInfFileName[MAX_PATH]; // Full path name
TCHAR DestinationInfFileName[MAX_PATH];
PTSTR DestinationInfFileNameComponent = NULL;

if (!SetupCopyOEMInf(SourceInfFileName,
                NULL,
                SPOST_PATH,
                0,
                DestinationInfFileName,
                ARRAYSIZE(DestinationInfFileName),
                NULL,
                &DestinationInfFileNameComponent)) {
    // Handle Error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Device Manager restarts the device after a driver update.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't. I even tried to unplug and plug the device again, it doesn't work, only the system restart helps. But like I said when I install the same driver manually (Device Manager -> Update driver) it takes effect immediately. Which means system code does something else after SetupCopyOEMInf() ?

Comment: If you uninstall the device through device manager (but do not remove the driver software) and install again, does that help?

Comment: @Preston no it doesn't help, basically it does the same thing.